# Java: Getting coordinates of a character, read out of a file

Tags: java, greenfoot

Good evening,

for hours I've been searching for a solution for this problem without success so I figured I'd ask a question here!
I have a question regarding reading characters / lines out of a textfile. I have been able to implement a function, which reads lines out of a file.
I am using Greenfoot (Java) to create a game which uses 32x32 blocks. I'd like to generate a world out of that textfile by getting the x- / y-coordinate of each "block" / "character" and placing it in the world. Would it be easier to use an array? My current code looks like this but I cannot figure out, how to get the coordinates. Could it work by using the hashcode it returns?

```
    public void readFile(String filename) throws IOException
{      
    String s;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    // Create BufferedReader and FileReader
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    // Try-catch block as exception handler 
    try {
        while((s = r.readLine()) != null) {

            // Create the blocks
            GrassBlock A = new GrassBlock();

            // Place them in the world
            addObject(A, x, y);

            // Test to see, if the blocks get recognised
            System.out.println(A);

            DirtBlock B = new DirtBlock();
            System.out.println(B);
            addObject(B, x, y);
        }            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Fehler beim Öffnen der Datei");
    } finally {

    }
}
```

My file looks somewhat like this:

```
0000000000
0000000000
AAAAAA00AA
BBBBBB00BB
```

I see that I have assigned the value "0" to both x and y so of course it can't work like this but how can I get that position? Right now the function is able to read the lines, generate the blocks at (0, 0) and showing the blocks in the console with a hashcode.

P.S Sorry if I have used the wrong term for some things, I am relatively new to programming!

Thank you,
Julian

Comment: Hints: 1. what is the format of your file, how are the coordinates/block type saved in the file? 2. generally it is more helpful to print the StackTrace (`e.printStackTrace()`) in the catch block, or at least the message and the class of the Exception

Comment: Maybe the line number is the _y_ coordinate and the position of each character in a line the _x_?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thank you! It is just a simple .txt file with 0, A's, B's etc. I'll change that, thanks!

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank you, can you just ask for the line number though or would you have to read out every x/y manually?

Comment: With a `BufferedReader` you'd have to keep a count of the lines yourself.  You could just add `++y;` at the bottom of  your `while` loop.  Or have a look at [LineNumberReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html).

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank you! But is it really that easy to add a "++y"? It would increase y every time we have read a line right? So what about the x-coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Just the very basic, without changing question code too much, not complete

1. determining the line number y:

   ```
   int y = 0;
   while ((s = ...) != null) {
       // do something with s
       y += 1;  // or y++
   }
   ```
2. similar for character position x inside the line and using `charAt` to retrieve the character:

   ```
   while ((s = ...) != null)  {
       int x = 0;
       while (x < s.length()) {
           char ch = s.charAt(x);
           // do something with ch, x, y - test for 0, A or B and add block
           x += 1;  // or x++
       }
       y += 1;  // or y++
   }
   ```

Notes: `x` is declared inside the outer (first) loop since it is not needed elsewhere; `x` is set to zero before the inner loop since it is the start of a new line; a `for` loop could be used instead of `while` - mostly better when using counters (like `x`)

Comment: Thank you for your help but for some reason I can't quite figure it out. What do you mean by "do something with"? I'm still quite flawed at understanding programming and I do not know what I would have to do. 
So I'm telling the program to read the first line while there's something there. Then I have to use the string to do something?

For the x-part I read the character, set x to 0 again and increase x until I have reached the end of the file. Then I increase y to go to the next line?


Do I have to put both while loops in a try-catch block?